# Windows 8.1 1024x600 not available

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I installed windows 8.1 on my netbook, acer aspire one ao531h-0bk which has a highest resolution of 1024x600. However I went to Screen resolution settings and I noticed that the resolution was 800x600. I have the option to change it from 640x480 to 800x600, but 1024x600 is not available. How can I fix it?
In both Ubuntu and windows 7, which I have installed, have their resolution on 1024x600 by default, so don't tell me that my netbook doen't support that resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Most screen resolution issues on laptop computers are due to the video driver.

For the ACER Aspire One AO531h, [Acer official support](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers/1110;-;AO531h) only provides drivers for Windows XP and Windows 7, so I would recommend you to try the official Intel driver for Windows 8. Just download and install the [Intel Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect), it will detect your hardware and will let you install the latest version of the specific driver you need.

Comment: It didn't find any drivers. Plus that it run on fullscreen, and it didn't fit properly in  800x600. Should I download the driver manually? My video card is an intel 945GMA. I searced and found some sollutions from registry, should I try them?

Comment: Looks like Intel does not provide support for Windows 8... The [Mobile Intel 945GM Express Chipset Family download page](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81509/Mobile-Intel-945GM-Express-Chipset-Family) only provides drivers for up to Windows 7. I've found a guide on [How to install intel display drivers in Windows 8](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-1656437/install-intel-display-drivers-windows.html), but it does not work with Windows 8.1.

Comment: If you are willing to make experiments, I'd try to download and install the 
[Windows 10 Insider Preview ISO](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-iso) to see if it fully supports the 945GMA.

Comment: Er, I already have this netbook triple booted and things started to get complicated. Also I don't have much HDD space. Here, http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/win-81-resolution/8ad401e0-9553-4f1c-8b11-ea6d4d53df70?auth=1 is this solution whith registry, should I try it?

Comment: Go ahead... but remember to make a backup copy of the registry key before modifying it. I've found a tutorial that also may help you: [How To: Install "legacy" Intel HD Graphics drivers on Windows 8](http://www.neowin.net/news/how-to-install-legacy-intel-hd-graphics-drivers-on-windows-8). It works by modifying the Windows 7 driver .inf file to allow it to be installed in Windows 8. It's tricky, but it may work.

Comment: It just can't find the Display1... on registry. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the software on windows and it installed a driver which supports 1024x600, and the system is faster